# No module named 'sendgrid_backend' in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, email, heroku, sendgrid

When sending an email on heroku I get this error:

```
No module named 'sendgrid_backend'
```

I have this set up in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend"
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY")
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
```

I also did install of sendgrid using pip and included it in the requirements.txt

Comment: Which sendgrid package specifically have you put in requirements.txt?

Comment: I put sendgrid==6.1.1

Comment: That's the wrong package then. The only one I can see that provides a `sendgrid_backend` module is this: https://github.com/sklarsa/django-sendgrid-v5 . So if that's what you're reading documentation for, that is the package you need to install.

Comment: yes, @solarissmoke is right, please visit this link https://pypi.org/project/django-sendgrid-v5/ or try ``pip install django-sendgrid-v5``

Answer (score 5):

I think this will help you 
First, install the package

```
pip install sendgrid-django
```

and then create requirements.txt, email backend should be like this

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"
```

or you can also do this

```
pip install django-sendgrid-v5
# https://github.com/sklarsa/django-sendgrid-v5
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend'
SENDGRID_API_KEY = '<SENDGRID_API_KEY>'
```

I think you should follow [this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/use_cases/django.md)

Comment: Followed those steps exactly but I get: No module named 'sgbackend'

Comment: @user8802333 I've edited my answer, try this one more method

Comment: Tried that, didn't work unfortunately. I've also tried EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' instead, but I get SMTPSenderRefused with  550, b'Unauthenticated senders not allowed'

Comment: I'm a little late to this but @user8802333, in order to resolve the unauthenticated senders error, you must verify the Sender Email from SendGrid console

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering around, this worked for me:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY")
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your sendgrid user name'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your sendgrid password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your sendgrid email'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: what's the difference between 'SENDGRID_API_KEY' and 'EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I just needed to switch to this:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

The sendgrid dependency is fine, just needed a different email backend setting.

Answer (score 0):

what you simply need to do is this:

`EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"`

and make sure you have installed sendgrid-django using:

```
pip install sendgrid-django
```

this just worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

But also if you get an SMTPSenderRefused with 550, b'Unauthenticated senders not allowed' error you have to go to the SendGrid website and authenticate your sender email, aka the email from which you want to send something

Answer (score 0):

If you are installed sendgrid for django package by `pip install sendgrid-django` you should use your `EMAIL_BACKEND` variable as below in
`settings.py`

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"
```

suppose your installed sendgrid for django package by `pip install django-sendgrid-v5` you should use your `EMAIL_BACKEND` variable as below in
`settings.py`

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend"
```